# Templated Rcpp function to erase NA values

Tags: r, templates, rcpp

I would write a function (using `Rcpp`) that removes all the `NA` values from a `R` vector.

Before doing so, I did a little test function through `Rcpp::cppFunction` function.

```
library(inline)
cppFunction('
  Vector<INTSXP> na_test(const Vector<INTSXP>& x) {
    return setdiff(x, Vector<INTSXP>::create(::traits::get_na<INTSXP>()));
  }
')
```

That works this way:

```
na_test(c(1, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA))
# [1] 1 2
```

After that I tried to generalize this function through the `C++` **template mechanism**.

So, in an external *.cpp* file (sourced through `sourceCpp` function), I've written:

```
template <int RTYPE>
Vector<RTYPE> na_test_template(const Vector<RTYPE>& x) {
    return setdiff(x, Vector<RTYPE>::create(::traits::get_na<RTYPE>()));
}

// [[Rcpp::export(na_test_cpp)]]
SEXP na_test(SEXP x) {
    switch(TYPEOF(x)) {
        case INTSXP:
            return na_test_template<INTSXP>(x);
        case REALSXP:
            return na_test_template<REALSXP>(x);
    }
    return R_NilValue;
}
```

This code **compiles but behaves differently** and I cannot explain why.

Infact:

```
na_test_cpp(c(1, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA))
# [1]  2 NA NA NA  1
```

Why the same function (apparently) behaves differently? What happens here?

Comment: Your example calls na_test_cpp, which your code does not show.

Comment: this expression `// [[Rcpp::export(na_test_cpp)]]` does not need to export the function (with the desired name) ?

Comment: my bad, overlooked it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following up on your answer, I would use something like this as the template:

```
template <int RTYPE>
Vector<RTYPE> na_omit_template(const Vector<RTYPE>& x) {
    int n = x.size() ;
    int n_out = n - sum( is_na(x) ) ;

    Vector<RTYPE> out(n_out) ;
    for( int i=0, j=0; i<n; i++){
        if( Vector<RTYPE>::is_na( x[i] ) ) continue ;
        out[j++] = x[i];
    }
    return out ;
}
```

So the idea is to first calculate the length of the result, and then just use `Rcpp` vector classes instead of `std::vector`. This will lead to less copies of the data.

---

With the development version of `Rcpp` (svn revision >= 4308), it works for me for all types, and we can then use our `RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR` dispatch macro instead of writing the `switch`:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP na_omit( SEXP x ){
     RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR( na_omit_template, x ) ;   
}
```

`na_omit` has been included in `Rcpp`(svn revision >= 4309), with a few modifications, i.e. it can handle named vectors and arbitrary sugar expressions.

Comment: Very elegant solution! ;)
Any idea to make it to work with STRSXP and CPLXSXP vectors?

Comment: Works for me for `STRSXP`. The complex version does not work because there was a bug in `Rcpp`, which is now fixed in revision 4308.

Comment: I have added `na_omit` to `Rcpp`, with a few modifications, e.g. it can handle named vectors and arbitrary sugar expressions.

Comment: very good !
Since I wish to use the `na_omit` that you added to `Rcpp`: when the new relase? :) Or I can install it from your SVN?

Comment: Now new release is planned at the moment. We don't release for each new feature or bug fix. Just get the source from r-forge and build it yourself: `svn checkout svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/rcpp/pkg/Rcpp`

Comment: Nice solution, but slower then `x[!is.na(x)]`.

Answer (score 1):

I've continued to investigate a solution about the templating problem (i.e. see @Sameer reply).

So I've written another function and now the templating mechanism works.

In an external `.cpp` file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
template <int RTYPE, class T>
Vector<RTYPE> na_omit_template(const Vector<RTYPE>& x) {
    typedef typename Vector<RTYPE>::iterator rvector_it;
    if (x.size() == 0) {
        return x;
    }
    std::vector<T> out;
    rvector_it it = x.begin();
    for (; it != x.end(); ++it) {
        if (!Vector<RTYPE>::is_na(*it)) {
            out.push_back(*it);
        }
    }
    return wrap(out);
}

// [[Rcpp::export(na_omit_cpp)]]
SEXP na_omit(SEXP x) {
    switch(TYPEOF(x)) {
        case INTSXP:
            return na_omit_template<INTSXP, int>(x);
        case REALSXP:                   
            return na_omit_template<REALSXP, double>(x);
        case LGLSXP:
            return na_omit_template<LGLSXP, bool>(x);
        case CPLXSXP:
            return na_omit_template<CPLXSXP, Rcomplex>(x);
        case RAWSXP:
            return na_omit_template<RAWSXP, Rbyte>(x);
        default:
            stop("unsupported data type");
    }
}
```

This function **removes the** `NA` **values**, that was my initial purpose.

Unfortunately, at the moment, **it does not work for all types of vectors**, as the `R` examples below show.

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp('file.cpp')
na_omit_cpp(as.integer(c(1, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA))) # OK
# [1] 1 1 2
na_omit_cpp(as.numeric(c(1, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA)))
# [1] 1 1 2
na_omit_cpp(c(NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA)) # OK
# [1] 1 3
na_omit_cpp(c(NA, 2L, 1, NA)) # OK
# [1] 2 1
na_omit_cpp(c(1.0, 1.1, 2.2, NA, 3, NA, 4)) # OK
# [1] 1.0 1.1 2.2 3.0 4.0
na_omit_cpp(c(1L, NaN, NaN, 0, NA)) # OK
# [1]   1 NaN NaN   0
na_omit_cpp(c(NA, NaN, 1.0, 0.0, 2.2, NA, 3.3, NA, 4.4)) # OK
# [1] NaN 1.0 0.0 2.2 3.3 4.4
na_omit_cpp(as.logical(c(1, 0, 1, NA))) # OK
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
na_omit_cpp(as.logical(c(TRUE, FALSE, NA, TRUE, NA))) # OK
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# empty vectors ?
na_omit_cpp(c(NA)) # OK
# logical(0)
na_omit_cpp(numeric(0)) # OK
# numeric(0)
na_omit_cpp(logical(0)) # OK
# logical(0)
na_omit_cpp(raw(0)) # OK
# raw(0)
na_omit_cpp(as.raw(c(40,16,NA,0,2))) # NO! (R converts it to 00)
# [1] 28 10 00 00 02
# Warning message ...
na_omit_cpp(as.complex(c(-1, 2, 1, NA, 0, NA, -1))) # NO! 
# [1] -1+0i  2+0i  1+0i    NA  0+0i    NA -1+0i
```

So, this function works in almost all cases except for `raw` vectors and `complex` vectors.

The **current open issues** are:

1. I'm not sure why this bug and I'd like to find out why. Any idea?
2. The previous templated function, as showed @Sameer, have a strange behaviour.
3. How to do to accept `character` vectors?

I thought clearly to `case STRSXP: return na_omit_template<STRSXP, ?>(x);` but this statement doesn't work substituting `std::string`, `Rcpp:String` to `?`.

Comment: I will make an actual reply later. There is no such thing as NA in the case of raw vectors.

Comment: @RomainFrancois you're right, I should have know (http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/get__na_8h.html).

Comment: Anyway I'm still trying to make this function to work for character vectors. At the moment: no progress.

Comment: `case STRSXP: return na_omit_template<STRSXP, String>(x);` works.

Answer (score 0):

The templating mechanism seems to work fine.

```
> na_test_cpp(as.numeric(c(1, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA)))
[1]  2 NA NA NA  1

> na_test_cpp(as.integer(c(1, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA)))
[1] 1 2
```

It is this code that is working for INTSXP but not for REALSXP

```
Vector<REALSXP> na_test_real(const Vector<REALSXP>& x) {
  return setdiff(x, Vector<REALSXP>::create(::traits::get_na<REALSXP>()));
}
```

Comment: Good point! I'm start to think also that can be a problem related to `setdiff` function, but I'm not sure. That's why I wrote here, hoping some guru help me :)

Comment: That is because `> evalCpp( "NA_REAL == NA_REAL" )` gives `[1] FALSE`. you cannot test for equality with numeric NA, you must use `is_na`.

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations:

```cpp
// naive
template <int RTYPE>
Vector<RTYPE> na_omit_impl(const Vector<RTYPE>& x) {
    std::size_t n = x.size();
    // Estimate out length
    std::size_t n_out = 0;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (Vector<RTYPE>::is_na(x[i])) continue;
        ++n_out;
    }
    // exit if no NAs
    if (n_out == n) return x;
    // allocate vector without filling
    Vector<RTYPE> res = no_init(n_out);
    // fill result vector
    for(std::size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (Vector<RTYPE>::is_na(x[i])) continue;
        res[j] = x[i];
        ++j;
    }
    return res;
}

// STL algorithms
template <int RTYPE>
struct not_na {
    typedef typename Vector<RTYPE>::stored_type type;
    bool operator() (const type& i) {
        return !Vector<RTYPE>::is_na(i);
    }
};

template <int RTYPE>
Vector<RTYPE> na_omit_impl(const Vector<RTYPE>& x) {
    // Estimate out length
    std::size_t n_out = std::count_if(x.begin(), x.end(), not_na<RTYPE>());
    // exit if no NAs
    if (n_out == x.size()) return x;
    // allocate vector without filling
    Vector<RTYPE> res = no_init(n_out);
    // fill result vector
    std::copy_if(x.begin(), x.end(), res.begin(), not_na<RTYPE>());
    return res;
}

// Rcpp sugar
template <class T>
T na_omit_impl(const T& x) {
    return x[!is_na(x)];
}

// Rcpp sugar
template <class T>
T na_omit_impl(const T& x) {
    return Rcpp::na_omit(x);
}
```

All implementations works with the `RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR` macro:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
RObject na_omit(RObject x){
    RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR(na_omit_impl, x);
}
```